# Regexp escape is not escaping substring separated by |

Tags: ruby

I have a string...

```
str = "bookworms|actuarial-consultants|uninterruptible-power-supply-(ups)-experts|c++programming-developers"
```

with special characters such as parentheses and `+` symbol.

can't match `uninterruptible-power-supply-(ups)-experts` and `c++programming-developers` unless I escape them manually like

```
bookworms|actuarial-consultants|uninterruptible-power-supply-\(ups\)-experts|c\+\+programming-developers
```

https://gyazo.com/d545ab1a8d7d178a6079f4b9cb125cce

My string can accomodate numerous substrings separated by `|` so I can't escape manually. And because, the string is generated thru a query method.

I tried `Regexp.escape` but it did not output the correct one. I can't still match `uninterruptible-power-supply-(ups)-experts` and `c++programming-developers`, even the normal substring like `bookworms`

https://gyazo.com/ae0bb43a1dc84f40deb18e3ed76d490e

the `escape` method is adding double `\\` to my string.

```
bookworms\\|actuarial\\-consultants\\|uninterruptible\\-power\\-supply\\-\\(ups\\)\\-experts\\|c\\+\\+programming\\-developers
```

Comment: What does "`I tried Regexp.escape but it did not output the correct one.`" mean? We have no idea what you tried, but `escape` will do what you tell it to. `Regexp.union` is also very useful for what you're trying to do. Read "[mcve]". We need more information to be able to help you.

Comment: What makes you think that `Regexp.escape` is doubling the backslashes? Keep in mind that `"\\"'` is one backslash, not two. If you `puts Regexp.escape(str)` I think you'll find that you're getting a properly escaped string.

Comment: It's properly escaped except the "or" are being escaped too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to tell what you're doing from the little you told us, but it sounds like you're not using `Regexp.escape` correctly.

Meditate on this:

```
str = "bookworms|actuarial-consultants|uninterruptible-power-supply-(ups)-experts|c++programming-developers"
Regexp.escape(str) 
# => "bookworms\\|actuarial\\-consultants\\|uninterruptible\\-power\\-supply\\-\\(ups\\)\\-experts\\|c\\+\\+programming\\-developers"
```

Notice that the "OR" (`|`) are being escaped which isn't desirable.

If you pass an array of the strings, then `union` will escape when necessary and concatenate each resulting escaped pattern into one large pattern:

```
Regexp.union(str.split('|')) 
# => /bookworms|actuarial\-consultants|uninterruptible\-power\-supply\-\(ups\)\-experts|c\+\+programming\-developers/
```

Using that in code:

```
regex = Regexp.union(str.split('|')) # => /bookworms|actuarial\-consultants|uninterruptible\-power\-supply\-\(ups\)\-experts|c\+\+programming\-developers/

'uninterruptible-power-supply-(ups)-experts'[regex] # => "uninterruptible-power-supply-(ups)-experts"
'c++programming-developers'[regex] # => "c++programming-developers"
```

shows the patterns are matching.

There are things to watch out for, but that's the basics.

Comment: Sn-man, I meant to post that on the question. I'm not sure your answer was up when I started. In any event, good answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm amazed with `union` then. This is new to me.

Comment: If you think `union` is interesting then you should look at Perl's [Regexp::Assemble](http://search.cpan.org/~rsavage/Regexp-Assemble-0.37/lib/Regexp/Assemble.pm). THAT is interesting.